# Basic shopping cart - Why is my Radio button state referenced incorrectly?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button, shopping-cart

I have a very simple "shopping cart" built in jQuery. (all on one page).
You add the items by checking a checkbox and remove them by unchecking the checkbox. However the state of the checkbox is not being referenced correctly and therefore I cannot enter the "add to cart" portion of the if else statement below:

```
$('#coreSetM').click(function()
{ 
    // Get the value of radio button
    var theMValue = $(this).attr("value");
    var theMPackage = $(this).attr("id");
    var theChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

    console.log("Value:"+theMValue+"\nPackage:"+theMPackage+"\nCheck Value:"+theChecked);

    if(theChecked==="false")
    {
        alert("False: "+theChecked);
        //do some add to cart stuff here with innerHTML
    }
    else
    {
        alert("True: "+theChecked)
        //do some remove from cart stuff here with innerHTML
    }
});
```

Despite the console logging the following:-

```
Value:118
Package:coreSetM
Check Value:false 

Value:118
Package:coreSetM
Check Value:true
```

It never enters the first part of the loop... I cannot figure out why since the value of theChecked is "false". (as determined in the console output.) Why is this?

Comment: Missing a ) after your last bracket at the end

Comment: Actually, this is just a portion of the code.. but I edited it as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a closing **)**

EDIT: You are comparing boolean to string by using `theChecked === 'false'`. Switch this to `theChecked === false` and you should be fine

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t6rfwbaf/

Comment: Works fine for me as shown in the fiddle. Might be an issue with conflicting code that we can't see

Answer (score 0):

Triple-equal is a strong comparison that also compares type of variable. In your code you're comparing boolean with String. Yuor if-statement will always result in `false`

Just do like this:

```
if(!theChecked)
{
    alert("False: "+theChecked);
    //do some add to cart stuff here with innerHTML
}
else
{
    alert("True: "+theChecked)
    //do some remove from cart stuff here with innerHTML
}
```

Comment: I already had that code and it doesn't work either.. it's the same thing anyway.

Comment: He is correct with his edit though. With the way you are comparing, it should be theChecked === false, not 'false'

Comment: Sorry added explanation after.   `true === "true"` will result in `false`

Comment: Yeah, the  "if(!theChecked)" code didn't work with my other jquery codes for some reason.. but cshanno's solution did so I chose that as the accepted answer. Thanks guys.

Comment: Strange that it didn't. But whaterver works, I guess. :)